# Different cartan subalgebras for loop algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, kac-moody-algebras

In [1] they say that the Cartan subalgebra of a loop algebra $\mathring{g} = \mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]\otimes g$ is $\mathring h = \mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]\otimes h$, where $h$ is the Cartan subalgebra of the simple Lie algebra $g$.

On the other hand, in [2] they say that the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathring g$ is $1\otimes h$ instead.

How can this be?

---

My guess:

Physicists actually care about the untwisted affine Kac Moody algebra $\hat g = \mathring g \oplus \mathbb C K \oplus \mathbb C \delta$, which has Cartan subalgebra generated by $\{1\otimes H^1,\ldots, 1\otimes H^r,K,\delta\}$, where the $H^i$ span $h$. In fact, adding the derivatoin $\delta$ has the effect of "shrinking" the Cartan subalgebra, which otherwise would be spanned by $\{t^n\otimes H^i,K\}_{i=1,...,r}^{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$. This is what I understood form DiFrancesco's book on CFT.

So Kerf seems to cut the middle man and focus directly on the part of the Cartan subalgebra which interests the physicists. I am not sure about this, though.

---

[1] Senesi, Prasad. "Finite-dimensional representation theory of loop algebras: a survey." Quantum affine algebras, extended affine Lie algebras, and their applications 506 (2010): 263-283.

[2] De Kerf, Eddy A., Gerard GA Bäuerle, and A. P. E. Ten Kroode. Lie algebras, Part 2: Finite and infinite dimensional Lie algebras and applications in physics. Vol. 7. Elsevier, 1997.

Comment: What is the definition of a Cartan subalgebra in the infinite-dimensional case? (Genuine question, I don't know what the answer is).

Comment: From the Kac-Moody perspective, there are two ways to construct an affine Lie algebra. One is by choosing an affine Cartan matrix $A$, and then constructing the associated Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}(A)$. The other is by taking a classical finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra $\mathring{\mathfrak{g}}$ and performing the loop extension followed by at least one (and maybe two) central extensions to get $\mathfrak{g} = \mathring{\mathfrak{g}}[t, t^{-1}] \oplus \mathbb{C}K \oplus \mathbb{C}d$. If $A$ and $\mathring{\mathfrak{g}}$ are chosen compatibly, then $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}(A)$.

Comment: The "shrinking" the Cartan subalgebra you are talking about is (I think) the wrong perspective. This sounds like you are trying to characterise the Cartan as the weight-zero elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ under the adjoint action. Without the second extension by the derivation $d$, there are not enough weights - even for $\mathring{\mathfrak{g}} = \mathfrak{sl}_2$, without the derivation $d$, every root space of the resulting algebra is infinite-dimensional. If you want to work with root spaces sensibly, you really need that derivation $d$.

Comment: @Joppy A Cartan subalgebra is a subalgebra which is nilpotent and is its own normalizer (see "Lie algebras with triangular decomposition" by Moody for example).

Comment: @Joppy Hmm aren't we saying the same thing then? The derivation does not commute with the $H^i_n$ for $n\ne 0$ and this is precisely why performing the extension by a derivation leaves the zero-weight spaces finite-dimensional (and that's what I meant by "shrinking").